# Fastest way to Convert List<?> to List<ObjectType>

Tags: java, generics, optimization, list

This is a Java question.

What is the fastest way to convert a `List<?>` to a `List<ObjectType>`? I am aware that this is possible through iteration please exclude that option.

Example by iteration,

```
final List<ObjectType> targetList = new ArrayList<ObjectType>();
// API returns List<?> so I have no choice.
List<?> resultList = resultSet.getResults(); 

// This is slow. Average list size is 500,000 elements.
while (resultList != null && !resultList.isEmpty()) {
    for (final Object object : resultList) {
        final ObjectType objectType = (ObjectType) object;
        targetList.add(objectType);
    }
    resultSet = someService.getNext(resultSet);
    resultList = resultSet.getList();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since you are using an array-based list, have you tried pre-allocating 500,000 elements (or about as much?). This may give a performance boost.

Comment: Now that I think about it, a LinkedList would eliminate the whole "pre-allocated memory" problem altogether.

Comment: Is there something removing elements from `resultList`, or is that `while` supposed to be an `if`?

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves, good question, I have modified the code. Thanks.

Comment: `LinkedList` should be slower. You'd be using masses of memory unnecessarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit scary but depending on context you could possibly get away with just casting:

```
final List<ObjectType> targetList = (List<ObjectType>)problemSolver.getResults();
```

Comment: I would go with that solution too, for this problem.

Comment: In general, this is not type-safe.

Comment: I take this approach, although I hide it behind a Lists.cast() utility method so that you don't actually need to tell the RHS what types are in the list (most of the time, anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

As Tom said above, if you know for a fact that everything in the original `List<?>` is an `ObjectType` -- as implied by the iteration code -- casting to `List<ObjectType>` will work just fine.

The only difference from the iteration code is that, if anything's *not* an `ObjectType`, in the iteration code the `ClassCastException` will happen when you're populating `targetList`, while with the straight cast, it'll happen when you're getting the values out. E.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<?> list = Arrays.<Object> asList('I', "am", "not", "homogeneous");
    List<Character> targetList = (List<Character>) list;

    int index = 0;
    try {
        for (Character c : targetList) {
            System.out.println(c);
            index++;
        }
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Reached " + index);
    }
}
```

prints

```
I
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String 
cannot be cast to java.lang.Character
    at Foo.main(Foo.java:100)
Reached 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Umm... if you are really dealing with 500,000 elements and expreriencing a performance issue, I'd bite the bullet (the bullet being compiler's "unchecked" warning) and cast it:

```
List<ObjectType> targetList = new ArrayList<ObjectType>((List<ObjectType>) resultList);
```

You can then use @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation to suppress the warning.

The above is, of course, assuming that `resultList` does not satisfy you in some way (perhaps it's unmodifiable or array-backed or what have you). Otherwise you can simply cast it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution depends on whether you want to ensure that the elements you put into `targetList` really are instances of `ObjectType` (or a subtype).

If you don't care, one of the solutions with an unsafe typecast will do.  Unless you need to copy, @Toms solution is better.  (You might need to copy if `getResults()` returns a linked list and your algorithm needs to use `targetList.get(int)` a lot.)  But beware that you might get an unexpected `ClassCastException` later on if your assumptions are incorrect.

If you need to be sure that there are no elements of the wrong type, then you have to use an iterator-based solution unless you know what kind of `List` type that `getResults()` gives you.  (If you can cast the result of `getResults()` to `ArrayList`, then indexing using `get(int)` should be faster than using an `Iterator`.  On the other hand, if the result is a `LinkedList`, then using `get(int)` to copy the list is `O(N**2)`!!)

How about this?

```
final List<?> resultList = problemSolver.getResults(); 

List<ObjectType> targetList;
if (resultList == null || resultList.isEmpty()) {
    targetList = Collections.empyList();
} else {
    int len = resultList.size();
    // it is important to preallocate the ArrayList with the
    // right size ... to conserve space and avoid copy on realloc
    // of the list's private backing array.
    targetList = new ArrayList<ObjectType>(len);
    if (resultList instanceof ArrayList) {
        // Copy using indexing - O(N) for ArrayLists
        ArrayList<?> arrayList = (ArrayList) resultList;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            targetList.add((ObjectType) (arrayList.get(i)));
        }
    } else {
        // Copy using iterator - O(N) for all sane List implementations,
        // but with a larger C than the best case for indexing.
        for (Object obj : resultList) {
            targetList.add((ObjectType) obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with iteration?

But as you wish:

```
final List<?> src = ...;
final int len = src.size();
final SomeType[] dstArray = new SomeType[len];
src.<SomeType>toArray(dstArray);
final List<SomeType> dst = java.util.Arrays.asList(dstArray);
```

Or:

(Disclaimer: Not so much as compiled.)

I prefer the iteration method.

Comment: Umm ... doesn't `src.toArray()` create a copy?  So you end up double copying.

Comment: Yes, although that should not be a huge issue in the scheme of things (still better than `LinkedList`!). I forgot the `toArray` with argument has strange bounds.